# How to print .bat script error into summary section when running a TFS build definition

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, tfs, invoke, build-definition

I'm running a .bat file [via the InvokeProcess activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312759/execute-sonar-runner-in-tfs-build/18343719#18343719) in a build process template.

The file is well executed along within a queued build but the error log (to the console) of my .bat file is not visible in the Summary section of the executed build report.

How can we print our message into this section?

ps.

When I put error command in my .bat file, the build is just continued without any error text displayed. The build even results as succeeded.

Comment: The InvokeProcess activity looks at the output streams from the program it is running.  I don't think you can force content from a batch file to write to stderr.  Your best option is to write your output which will show up in the diagnostic log and then use exit /b %EXITCODE% to indicate the script completed with error.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson How can we write output into `diagnostic log`?

Comment: All output from both stderr stdout goes into the diagnostic log.  There is no way to make it go to the summary section.