# Error when execute within a TFS build definition

Tags: batch-file, command-line, tfs, tfsbuild, build-definition

When I tried to call command-line to get latest update for my TFS mapped folder

`TF get /recursive`

The call complete successfully from the `run` window of Windows 7.

However, when I put the call into a .bat file and run it via `InvokeProcess` within a build definition ([guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18343719/248616) to do that), it failed.

The message is as below.

> Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by
>   running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'

What happens? How can I get around with that?

Comment: Did you sepcify the workingdirectory of the InvokeProcess activity to the Sources directory of the Build Definition? Which version of TFS?

Comment: No I didn't specify the working directory. I call `CD /D` in my batch script. I'll try to set the working folder then. TFS version is 2012

Comment: Setting the `Working Directory` in the properties of InvokeProcess activity but the error stay the same.

Comment: are some other variables set (Arguments)?

Comment: Where did you `cd /d` to? Can you confirm that the user the build is executing under has a workspace configured for that directory?

Comment: I leave the arguments empty Oswald

Comment: I `cd` to the workspace folder where I map to my Source Control path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for my issue is that the build agent execute my .bat file under a different Windows account which is something like `NTSERVICE`; when I run it directly, my TFS login account was used (which was previously remembered in Windows 7 Credential Manager)

So the solution is to put in the login name and password as `TF get /login:SomeTFSUsername,SomePassword` (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771295/changing-login-account-used-for-tf-command-line))

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because when you run the command locally, the folder you're downloading is mapped to a workspace. When you execute the command in your build, it's running under the build service account, which *doesn't* have a workspace mapped for the folder you're specifying.

You shouldn't need to use the `tf get` command as part of your build. When you configure your build, you can specify which folders should be mapped in the workspace on the "Source Settings" tab. The build process will handle making sure the contents of the folders you map in your workspace are present automatically.