# Changing login account used for TF command-line

Tags: authentication, command-line, tfs

When using the command-line version of TFS 2012, we call

`TF.exe get $/Path/To/Team/Project/Some/Folder /recursive`

And with that call from command line prompt, my command succeeded.

I do not put in any username/password for this call.

I want to change the user for this command but going for `TF.exe /?` give me no choice.

How can I change login account used for TF command-line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is here

```
TF.exe get /login:yourUsername,yourPassword ...
```

We can see manual for that from

```
TF get /?
```

Cheers

Comment: This didn't work - it still tried to use the previously-chosen user.

Comment: To avoid changes in your existing workspace, you'd better login with workspaces command: `tf workspaces /login:o`

Answer (score 2):

Hit `Shift + Right click` on `Visual Studio Command Prompt` (in Start menu) and select `Run as different user`. Enter the user credentials when asked and it will open the command prompt and run as that user. After that you can run tf.exe command as that user.

You will have to make sure user has permission to the workspace for that folder. You can use Public workspaces to allow multiple users to use same workspace mappings.

Comment: I'm looking for automation script to change the login account. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I had Jenkins running as a service and this helped me too. Start > Services > right click service > properties > "Log On" tab

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the runas command in DOS.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx

Comment: Can we have parameter for password for `runas` instead of waiting for the prompt? I need someway to write automation script.